# Does "global" keyword for variables exists in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

can we use like `global let name = "lucky"` in reactjs , i have seen about using window and environment variables , but we all know that this will be the easy and best way in other languages

Comment: You can use **Redux**  or Flux library that can handle data or state globally. and you can pass it easily through all your components. there is no thing such `global let name = "lucky"` in react js

Comment: thanks for comment , again i am new to redux or flux , which one i go for best and also for future usages ?

Comment: Redux API surface is tiny unlike most Flux libraries and it preserves all the benefits of Flux.  the best option for you is **Redux**

Comment: No, `global` is not a keyword in JavaScript, and the line you mention is a syntax error.

Comment: What is your problem that you're trying to solve? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i had a situation like need to assign a const var inside a function and that var is require outside of the function

Comment: Then just leave out the `const`, make it a simple assignment, and declare the variable with `let` in the outer scope. But no, this is almost always the wrong approach, since the variable will be `undefined` until the function is called. Can you please [edit] your question to include the exact code where you need this?